# Mapping @ManyToMany relationship with hibernate annotation

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, annotations

**UPDATE**: I saw the database relationships and I realized that the Module table has two references to the Unit Table (nid, unnr), but Unit Table doesnt have a reference to Module Table, it has only to subrack table using the nid.

Comment: Did you try to run the generate query on the Database directly and see if it returned any values ?  Do you have any data in those tables ?

Comment: But I think that my mapping is incorrect. So it returns me an empty list.

Comment: Try to build it step-by-step first try one directional and then move to bi-directional.  In Unit.java remove the annotations @ManyToMany(targetEntity=Module.class,mappedBy="units"). And in Module .java remove the attribute referencedColumnName and give a try.

Comment: I removed these annotations. I will post the updates. But I am still getting emptylist.

Comment: Sorry, I've misread your question. Can you remove the relationship between your two tables to see if you still get a empty list?

Comment: I removed. And I am still getting it. D.Rodrigues you know if I have to map all the PK, because in module table I have 3 PK`s.

Comment: take a look on the update please

Answer (score 1):

first of all, all your code that is currently showing is mixing up some things...

You define a @JoinTable annotation, which means that you have 3 tables, 1 with units, 1 with modules and one with the id's of both entities in it...

2nd remark I have is that you talk about a One-To-Manny relationship between a module and units, but in your example code you put a Many-To-Many...

If I follow your description I would build it like this in code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "unit")
public class Unit {
@Column(name = "nid")
private int nid;
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "unnr")
private int unnr;
@Column(name = "unhwtype")
private int unhwtype;
@Column(name = "unslot")
private int unslot;
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "nid")
private Module module;

@Entity
@Table(name = "module")
public class Module {
@Column(name = "nid")
private int nid;
@Id
@Column(name = "mpos")
private int mpos;
@Column(name = "mhwtype")
private int mhwtype;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "module", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
private Set units;
```

The problem her is that I'm not sure if this is going to work, since the nid is not an ID column in the module Entity, I think you will need to change your design so that nid is an Id column... You can give it a try with this code and hope it works, otherwise change the nid in the module Entity to an ID..

Comment: Yoeri, I changed the code as you said. But the lists are still empty. I will try to put de nid as an ID, but if I do this I keep the Id annotation of mpos or I remove it and just put the Id annotation of nid ?

Comment: Hi Murilo, I assume Hibernate can't work with 2 @Id annotations on the same entity so I would suggest to just put the Id on Nid and remove it from the Mpos.